# FusedLocationProviderClient doesn't work when using "GPS only" mode or "Wifi-network"

Tags: android, location, android-gps, fusedlocationproviderclient

I've implemented the Fused Location provider client and everything seems to work fine when using "GPS, wifi, network" mode, but when you are outside of a building and the mode is set to "GPS only", the location is not displayed anymore. Do you know what can cause the problem?

[image]